# mediawiki api search query with multiple expressions

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

I'd like to run a query for an artist's names. An artist could have a stage name, a full name (latin), korean name, nickname, etc.

I can't find **how to seperate these names in a query URL**.

```
https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srnamespace=6&srlimit=500&format=json&srsearch=Taeyeon|Kim Tae-yeon|Taengoo|김태연
```

If I run the query for only 1 name, it brings the results, but got nothing with more names.

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyword `OR` instead of `|`.

That means, run the following query:

```
https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srnamespace=6&srlimit=500&format=json&srsearch=Taeyeon OR "Kim Tae-yeon" OR Taengoo OR 김태연
```